# Conditional relationship creation using LOAD CSV in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

My task is to import a number of friend or follow relationships into a simple neo4j graph db.  My input data is a csv with the following structure:

```
owner,friend,type
Bob,Charlie,friend
Alice,Chris,follower
```

In the above example Charlie is a friend of Bob and Chris is a follower of Alice.  I want to bulk import these into neo4j using `LOAD CSV` but I'm having trouble creating the conditional relationships during import.  The import code looks something like:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:./graph.csv" AS csvLine
WITH csvLine.owner AS owner,
     csvLine.friend AS friend,
     csvLine.type AS Type

MERGE (o:Person { name: owner })
MERGE (c:Person { name: friend })
MERGE (u)<-[:IS_FRIEND {type: Type}]-(c);
```

I'd rather have two types of relationships `IS_FRIEND` and `FOLLOWS`.  But when I try conditional statements like:

```
CASE WHEN Type == "friend" THEN MERGE (u)<-[:IS_FRIEND]-(c) ELSE (u)<-[:FOLLOWS]-(c);
```

I receive syntax errors on the use of `CASE`

Is there a way to make conditional relationships during bulk import from csv like this?

Answer (score 0):

Strange this was not answered. YOu can look at https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/06/17/neo4j-load-csv-handling-conditionals/

```
// cards
FOREACH(n IN (CASE WHEN csvLine.type IN ["yellow", "red", "yellowred"] THEN [1] else [] END) |
  FOREACH(t IN CASE WHEN team = home THEN [home] ELSE [away] END |
    MERGE (stats)-[:RECEIVED_CARD]->(card {time: csvLine.time, type: csvLine.type})
  )     
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to APOC Procedures, you can use [conditional procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_conditional_cypher_execution) to handle this case, it can be a bit more readable than the FOREACH trick.

```
MERGE (o:Person { name: owner })
MERGE (c:Person { name: friend })
WITH o, c, Type
CALL apoc.do.when(Type = 'friend', "MERGE (o)<-[r:IS_FRIEND]-(c) RETURN r", "MERGE (o)<-[r:FOLLOWS]-(c) RETURN r", {o:o, c:c}) YIELD value
SET value.r.type = Type
```

The last SET line is there primarily because you can't end a query with a CALLed procedure, so we need some kind of SET operation. Feel free to replace with anything else that makes sense for your data.